# Excel table using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

I have an excel file with 2 tables on the first sheet. Can I pull Excel tables using Powershell. Currently using Powershell v3 with Excel 2007.

I'm aiming to convert those table to CSV file separately for other purpose.

The table should be reference by tables name as the table would not be located on fixed cell with fixed ranges. Is it possible to do this using Powershell?

Comment: Are you hoping to reference tables by name, or are you ok with just accessing them by cell reference?This shouldn't be too hard to do if you know the location of the tables, and their ranges won't change.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I was hoping reference tables by name. Currently I don't have the actual excel data, the data will come from a few department with different ranges I guess. So need to reference it by table name, as that was the clue that is given by my boss. I have playing with powershell command, but i don't find anything that would take me to the tables. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Is there some reason why using excel to dump the tables to csv files is unacceptable?  For example, is this too manual?

Comment: I don't see anything in the MSDN entry for the Excel.Application that specifically references tables other than QueryTables and PivotTables.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

WalterMitty : the other department use excel to do their work. It quite manual I guess. I would love to use the data for some automation app (under my boss order). As I don't have the actual data yet and my boss said that i should reference the excel by the table name(not sheets or file) that is I would try to do this using powershell.
@TheMadTechnician : so it is not possible, please add an answer so I can mark it as answered. 

Thank you for both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the MSDN entry for Excel automation and could not find a way to reference tables by name. Does that mean it's not there and I missed it? No, but it means that it's not obvious, and quite likely means that it is not there at all.

Next, can this be done another way? Probably, yes. I'm not half bad at performing some digital voodoo with Excel and PowerShell, so I would say that while you can  not reference the table by name you can probably find the table by other means if you really wanted to pursue automating this task. Once you get the spreadsheet in your hands take a look at it and see if there's something you could search for with the table, and try and work another way at it, and if you run into roadblocks come on back and we'll see if we can assist you with tackling them. But for now, I'm sorry, but it does not look like you can reference a table by name from Excel's com object.

Comment: It look like I really have to play with the cell ranges, hope they are all well organised.
I will come by again for another problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could easily be done by such reference:

```
$ColumnInATable = $AWorksheet.Range("TableOneName[AnyColumnName]")
```

In this case **TableOneName** is the name of the desired table on the Excel worksheet, where **AnyColumnName** can speak for itself.
Actually, a table is just a named region in Excel and therefore must be treated as such.